# AddRecord to jTable jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I thought this should be ok to populate `jTable` with records. I have tried it several times but it only displays:

> No data available

What am I doing wrong?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testjtable').jtable({
        title: 'Table of Items',
        paging: "true",
        sorting: "true",
        defaultSorting: "ITEM ASC",
        selecting: "true",
        multiselect: "true",
        selectingCheckboxes: "true",
        selectOnRollClick: "yes",
        actions: {
            listAction: '', 
            createAction: '',
            updateAction: '',
            deleteAction: ''
        },
        fields: {
            ItemId: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            Item: {
                title: 'ITEM',
                width: '30%'
            },
            Relationship: {
                title: 'RELATIONSHIP',
                width: '20%'
            },
            Type: {
                title: 'TYPE',
                width: '20%',
                type: 'date',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },
            Parent: {
                title: 'PARENT',
                width: '20%'
            }
        }
    });

    //('#testjtable').jTable('load');
    $('#testjtable').jtable('addRecord', {
        record: {
            ItemId:01,
            Item: 'Lagos',
            Relationship: 'is a',
            Type: 'State',
            Parent: Nigeria
        },
        clientOnly:true
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testjtable"></div>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jtabletest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to enclose your the for the parent column in  quotes .

```
           $('#testjtable').jtable('addRecord', {
                record: {
                    ItemId:01,
                    Item: 'Lagos',
                    Relationship: 'is a',
                    Type: 'State',
                    Parent: 'Nigeria'   // added quotes to the string data
                },
                clientOnly:true
            });
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks. It's still giving the same status: "No data available!" I have cleared history on the browser but still the same status. What exactly could be wrong?

Comment: I am seeing these errors on the console:Uncaught TypeError: Object format error! has no method 'getFullYear' jquery-ui.js:8941
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/Ken4ward/Desktop/metro/blue/loading.gif
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/Ken4ward/Desktop/metro/column-sortable.png
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. The errors seems to have come from missing image jQuery file

Comment: @kehinde: which version of `jQueryUI` and `jtable` are you using in your page ? also there are few image files missing, check the path once.

Comment: I am using jquery-ui-1.10.4 and jtable.2.4.0. Maybe they are not compatible? what do you think?

Comment: well as per the official jquery site , it says `jquery >=1.9.1` & `jqueryui >=1.9.2` are compatible with  `jtable 2.4.0` . ref:http://plugins.jquery.com/jTable/

Comment: if possible could you create jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net. we can sort it out over there

Comment: Ok. I'll do that now. Thanks.

Comment: @kehinde: do you have the cdn of jtable ? because that lib is missing, rest are fine

Comment: Thanks. Only hearing of it for the very first time. Very new to jQuery. where do i get it from? how do i add it to the file?

Comment: just do one thing, just host a jsfile with data present from this github link.https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/blob/master/lib/jquery.jtable.min.js . so that we`ll have this file online , so that we can refer it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Type" field is set to date type and you're giving it a string "State".

Try something like "2014-05-13" with displayFormat: "yy-mm-dd".

Answer (score 0):

If paging is enabled the client only addition will not work. It is a bug